# Compare the sum of two big numbers with another

Tags: c++, arrays

How can I compare the sum between to big numbers to another one (considering they are all in an array) in C++ ?
All the numbers are up to 1 000 000 000, so I can't simply add them into the array.
I tried the followings:
- Divide the numbers by 1000 -> Cannot store floats into arrays
- Subtract 10000 from all the numbers with a bool solution -> Cannot define negative pointer into an array

So, how can I do it ?

Comment: Use a bigger data-type, like `long long` which is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits? Or for floating point data types, `double` or `long double` (if supported) instead of `float`?

Comment: 'long long' still doesn't work. I get this: "size of array 'b' is too large"

Comment: Are you trying to create an array of *one billion elements*? If you're using a 32-bit `int` then that's almost 4GB or memory. Local variables are normally stored on the stack, which is usually in the single-digit MB range (Windows typically have a single MB while Linux have a default 8 MB stack size). If you have plenty of virtual memory then you could dynamically allocate the array (or use `std::vector`). Otherwise you need to come up with another data-structure or algorithm to do what you want to do.

Comment: Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's very hard to know what you are trying to do right now, and code says more than a thousand pictures. It also seems you have two problems, and it's not clear which one you are asking about.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you want to compare A+B to C, all numbers positive.

If A>C, then it must be the case that A+B>C.
Otherwise, compare B to C-A.